# Django Json Response - Problems at showing count fields

Tags: python, json, django

I'm having problems to show my fields correctly to a JSON.

This is the view function

```
query = "SELECT sede.id, sede.Nombre as nombre, count(distinct(mesa.id)) as 'mesas' , count(distinct(plan.id)) as planes, count(distinct(diagnostico.id)) as diagnosticos                FROM ubicacion_sede sede                join ubicacion_subregion subregion on subregion.Sede_id = sede.id                join ubicacion_region region on region.id = subregion.Region_id                join ubicacion_pais pais on pais.id = region.Pais_id                join comunidades_comunidad comunidad on comunidad.Subregion_id = subregion.id                 join comunidades_mesa mesa on mesa.Comunidad_id = comunidad.id and mesa.Estado = 'Activo'                left join comunidades_planesdeaccion plan on plan.Mesa_id = mesa.id                left join comunidades_diagnostico diagnostico on diagnostico.Mesa_id = mesa.id                group by sede.id, sede.Nombre"


respuesta = Sede.objects.raw(query)
respuesta_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', respuesta, fields=('nombre', 'mesas', 'planes', 'diagnosticos'))
content = JsonResponse(respuesta_serialized, safe=False)
```

and this is the JSON I get from this

```
"[{\"model\": \"ubicacion.sede\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {}}, {\"model\": \"ubicacion.sede\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {}}, {\"model\": \"ubicacion.sede\", \"pk\": 6, \"fields\": {}}, {\"model\": \"ubicacion.sede\", \"pk\": 12, \"fields\": {}}, {\"model\": \"ubicacion.sede\", \"pk\": 22, \"fields\": {}}]"
```

Here I have two problems

1. Why i'm not getting the fields i want
2. Why I get the JSON formatted like \" and not "

Thanks in advance for your answer, I've been turning SOF upside down but couldn't get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, i resolve this making the json via a template in HTML, it was way easier.

I know maybe is not the best thing to do, but i have to resolve it anyway.

Thanks